# Getting error while saving the annotation entity in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to save the annotation entity in CRM 2011 using the following code :

```cs
var annotationContext = new CrmOrganizationServiceContext(crmOrganizationService);
var annotation = annotationContext.CreateEntity("annotation");
annotationContext.AddObject(annotation);
// Setting the account id.
entity.SetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("objectid", "account", "Guid of the account");    
entity.iCrmSetPropertyValue(AnnotationDefinition.ColumnsName.DocumentBody,Convert.ToBase64String(new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes("Sample Annotation Text")));
entity.iCrmSetPropertyValue("isdocument",true);
entity.iCrmSetPropertyValue(AnnotationDefinition.ColumnsName.Mime, "text/plain");
entity.iCrmSetPickListValue(AnnotationDefinition.ColumnsName.ObjectType, 1);
entity.iCrmSetPropertyValue(AnnotationDefinition.ColumnsName.Subject, "CompanyLogo");
annotationContext.SaveChanges();
```

The save changes method fails with following error in the eventviewer of the crm server :

> The Web Service plug-in failed in OrganizationId: ###########;
>   SdkMessageProcessingStepId: #####; EntityName: annotation; Stage: 30;
>   MessageName: Create; AssemblyName:
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin,
>   Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35; ClassName:
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin; Exception:
>   Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is
>   not valid.    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.EntityNameReferenceAttributeConverter.ConvertToBusinessEntity(Object
>   value, AttributeMetadata attributeMetadata, Dictionary`2
>   abbrvToChildAttributeMetadata, ICrmConversionContext context,
>   BusinessEntity target)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.EntityToBusinessEntityConverter.ConvertUsingExistingBusinessEntity(EntityMetadata
>   entityMetadata, ICrmConversionContext conversionContext, Entity
>   entity, BusinessEntity businessEntity)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessEntity.Converter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.ConversionHelpers.Convert(ICrmConversionContext
>   conversionContext, Object source, Type destinationType)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.DictionaryMapper.Map(ParameterCollection
>   inputs, ICrmConversionContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext
>   context)

Comment: You have type conflicts: `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid`

Comment: Are you actually sending `"Guid of the account"` or is that just for demonstration purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the `annotation` variable to the context, but updating the entity object.